# Why is Service.onBind abstract in Android

Tags: java, android, android-service, abstract-class

Of all the methods in Service, why is onBind abstract?

Most of the Services I have seen/written just return null.

Comment: The example in the documentation doesn't return null... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: @cricket_007 I get that, but in practice how often is it implemented? I've been working with Android for a while, and have only seen it implemented very rarely.

Comment: Never written a Service myself, either ;)